# regarding uasage of read() and readLine() in java?

Tags: java

Im unable to read the string using the following code in java. Please, let me know what changes need to be made.
The code is as follows:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ioreadver1
{
    public static void main(String [] args)throws Exception`
    {   
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("ioreadver1ans.txt")));
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    //taking input
    String str1 = "Enter the Character:";
    System.out.println("Enter the Character: ");
    char ch =(char)br.read();
    System.out.println("Enter the String:");
    String str= br.readLine();
    pw.write(str1);
    pw.write(ch);
    pw.write("\n");
    pw.write(str);
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit your previous question. Don't [repost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218439/regaring-usage-of-read-and-readline-functions). This question will almost certainly be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hy
please look your code. i just rearranged your function calling

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("ioreadver1ans.txt")));
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            //taking input
            String str1 = "Enter the Character:";
           // 
            System.out.println("Enter the String:");
            String str= br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the Character: ");
            char ch =(char)br.read();

            pw.write(str1);
            pw.write(ch);
            pw.write("\n");
            pw.write(str);
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Th problem (I think) is to do with this:

```
  char ch = (char) br.read();
```

This reads exactly one character from the input stream.  But when you ask the user to enter a character, he / she will need to enter keystrokes; i.e. the character, followed by the ENTER key.  And the ENTER key results in at least one more character - a CR, NL, or CRNL ... depending on the OS.

But you don't explicitly read and discard the end-of-line characters.  Instead, they are left for this statement to read:

```
  String str= br.readLine();
```

... and that gives you an empty string!

Comment: this was insightful and something I couldn't find in the docs

Answer (score 0):

After calling `br.read()`, the character will be read, but there will still be a newline left in the buffer. Add an extra call to `br.readLine()` after the first read to remove this.

Or simply use `br.readLine()` instead of `br.read()` and extract the character from the result.